# unable to get hashicorp / vault

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault

I need to use kmac Hashicorp's Vault implementation. However, when I run the code, the following simple import:

```
import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk/helper/kmac"
)
```

throws this error:  `no required module provides package github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac; to add it: go get github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac`

If I run:

`go get github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac`

I get:

`go get: module github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk@upgrade found (v0.2.0), but does not contain package github.com/hashicorp/vault/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac`

I also tested to download the latest version but I get the same error. Can I get help?

Comment: There's no `kmac` [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/tree/master/sdk/helper). Nor anywhere [in the vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/search?q=kmac) for that matter. Did you get the name right? Are you sure you're looking for `kmac` and not something else? If you're indeed looking for `kmac` are you sure it is supposed to be in vault?

Comment: Probably relates to my comment in an earlier question, where I suggested to use this: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/484a6febabe7/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac.go. You're probably better off simply copying the file. Vault comes with a slew of other stuff you don't need, and their module layout has caused me trouble as well in the past.